# Consolidate object value containing array : Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having array of objects that look like this:

```
const test = {
  cat1: {
    id: "c1",
    name: "category1",
    items: [
      {
        itemName: "item1",
        points: 1,
        used: true
      },
      {
        itemName: "item2",
        points: 3,
        used: false
      },
      {
        itemName: "item3",
        points: 5,
        used: true
      }
    ]
  },
  cat2: {
    id: "c2",
    name: "category2",
    items: [
      {
        itemName: "item4",
        points: 7,
        used: true
      },
      {
        itemName: "item5",
        points: 9,
        used: false
      }
    ]
  },
  cat3: {
    id: "c3",
    name: "category3",
    items: [
      {
        itemName: "item6"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I want the output to be an object something like this

```
{ available: 12 , used: 13}
```

Need to go over the items array, and derive the `available` and `used` based on if `used` boolean under each object. If its true, add it with `used` else add it with `available` entry.Some object may not have `points` and `used` , those need to be ignored.

Can someone help with the approach

Code that I tried

```
const result = Object.values(test).reduce(
  (acc, obj) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < obj.items.length; i++) {
      if (obj.items[i].used) {
        return (acc.used = acc.used + obj.items[i].used);
      } else acc.available = acc.available + obj.items[i].available;
    }
  },
  { available: 0, used: 0 }
);
```

Comment: What is `ob.tiles`? There's no `tiles` property in any of your objects. It seems like you just copied that code. You made no attempt to adapt it to your specific problem. You're never adding to the `available` and `used` properties.

Comment: Please make an actual attempt to solve your problem, then we can help you fix it.

Comment: If the code in the reduce function doesn't refer to `used` and `available`, you're not really trying.

Comment: @Barmar, Sorry the question was half cooked. I have updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flat the arrays and add with the help of an array.

```js
const
    test = { cat1: { id: "c1", name: "category1", items: [{ itemName: "item1", points: 1, used: true }, { itemName: "item2", points: 3, used: false }, { itemName: "item3", points: 5, used: true }] }, cat2: { id: "c2", name: "category2", items: [{ itemName: "item4", points: 7, used: true }, { itemName: "item5", points: 9, used: false }] }, cat3: { id: "c3", name: "category3", items: [{ itemName: "item6" }] } },
    result = Object
        .values(test)
        .flatMap(({ items }) => items)
        .reduce((r, { points, used }) => {
            if (points) r[['available', 'used'][+used]] += points;
            return r;
        }, { available: 0 , used: 0 });

console.log(result);
```

2nd request.

```js
const
    test = { cat1: { id: "c1", name: "category1", items: [{ itemName: "item1", points: 1, used: true }, { itemName: "item2", points: 3, used: false }, { itemName: "item3", points: 5, used: true }] }, cat2: { id: "c2", name: "category2", items: [{ itemName: "item4", points: 7, used: true }, { itemName: "item5", points: 9, used: false }] }, cat3: { id: "c3", name: "category3", items: [{ itemName: "item6" }] } },
    result = Object
        .values(test)
        .flatMap(({ items }) => items)
        .reduce((r, { points = 0, used = false }) => {
            r.used += used && points;
            r.available += points;
            return r;
        }, { available: 0 , used: 0 });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @Nina Scholz, Incase I want the available to be the overall points, how can I modify this? { available: 25 , used: 13}

Answer (score 0):

Do first a `map()` and `.flat()`, than the `.reduce()`:

```js
const input = { cat1: { id: "c1", name: "category1", items: [ { itemName: "item1", points: 1, used: true }, { itemName: "item2", points: 3, used: false }, { itemName: "item3", points: 5, used: true } ] }, cat2: { id: "c2", name: "category2", items: [ { itemName: "item4", points: 7, used: true }, { itemName: "item5", points: 9, used: false } ] }, cat3: { id: "c3", name: "category3", items: [ { itemName: "item6" } ] } };

const result = Object.values(input).map(obj => obj.items).flat().reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if(obj.used) {
    acc.used += obj.points;
  } else {
    acc.available += obj.points || 0;
  }
  return acc;
}, {available: 0, used: 0})
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
{
  "available": 12,
  "used": 13
}
```

**UPDATE 1** to get overall points for available:

```js
const input = { cat1: { id: "c1", name: "category1", items: [ { itemName: "item1", points: 1, used: true }, { itemName: "item2", points: 3, used: false }, { itemName: "item3", points: 5, used: true } ] }, cat2: { id: "c2", name: "category2", items: [ { itemName: "item4", points: 7, used: true }, { itemName: "item5", points: 9, used: false } ] }, cat3: { id: "c3", name: "category3", items: [ { itemName: "item6" } ] } };

const result = Object.values(input).map(obj => obj.items).flat().reduce((acc, obj) => {
  acc.available += obj.points || 0;
  if(obj.used) {
    acc.used += obj.points;
  }
  return acc;
}, {available: 0, used: 0})
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
{
  "available": 25,
  "used": 13
}
```

Comment: You can combine `map` and `flat` with `.flatmap()`

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thoeny, Incase I want the available to be the overall points, how can I modify this? { available: 25 , used: 13}

Comment: @lrr97: See UPDATE 1

Answer (score 0):

You're returning on the first iteration of the loop. You need to increment `acc.used` or `acc.available` in the loop, but only return `acc` at the end of the loop.

You need to change the parameter of the callback function to `curr` to match how you use it inside the function.

`obj.items[i].used` is not a number to add. You should just increment the counter. And there's no `obj.items[i].available`.

```js
const test = {
  cat1: {
    id: "c1",
    name: "category1",
    items: [{
        itemName: "item1",
        points: 1,
        used: true
      },
      {
        itemName: "item2",
        points: 3,
        used: false
      },
      {
        itemName: "item3",
        points: 5,
        used: true
      }
    ]
  },
  cat2: {
    id: "c2",
    name: "category2",
    items: [{
        itemName: "item4",
        points: 7,
        used: true
      },
      {
        itemName: "item5",
        points: 9,
        used: false
      }
    ]
  },
  cat3: {
    id: "c3",
    name: "category3",
    items: [{
      itemName: "item6"
    }]
  }
};

const result = Object.values(test).reduce(
  (curr, obj) => {
    obj.items.forEach(item => {
      if (item.used) {
        curr.used++;
      } else {
        curr.available++;
      }
    });
    return curr;
  }, {
    available: 0,
    used: 0
  });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar Incase I want the available to be the overall points, how can I modify this? { available: 25 , used: 13}

Comment: Just do `curr.available++` outside the `if`.